# GCD dispatch_set_target_queue function's 1st parameter type

Tags: multithreading, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

The function prototype is this:

```
void dispatch_set_target_queue(
   dispatch_object_t object,
   dispatch_queue_t queue);

typedef union {
   struct dispatch_object_s *_do;
   struct dispatch_continuation_s *_dc;
   struct dispatch_queue_s *_dq;
   struct dispatch_queue_attr_s *_dqa;
   struct dispatch_group_s *_dg;
   struct dispatch_source_s *_ds;
   struct dispatch_source_attr_s *_dsa;
   struct dispatch_semaphore_s *_dsema;
   struct dispatch_data_s *_ddata;
   struct dispatch_io_s *_dchannel;
   struct dispatch_operation_s *_doperation;
   struct dispatch_fld_s *_dfld;
} dispatch_object_t __attribute__((transparent_union));
```

I am confused why below code could pass compiling???

```
dispatch_queue_t queueA = dispatch_queue_create("com.effectiveobjectivec.queueA", NULL);
dispatch_queue_t queueB = dispatch_queue_create("com.effectiveobjectivec.queueB", NULL);
dispatch_set_target_queue(queueB, queueA); // will set queueA as queueB's target
```

I don't see any field in `dispatch_object_t Union` is a `dispatch_queue_t`, so how can queueB argument cause no compile errors?

Also. I wonder what "`struct dispatch_object_s *_do;`" field is? What is "`struct dispatch_queue_s *_dq;`"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of `dispatch_object_t` as the "base class" of all the dispatch object types.

In "plain" C this uses the [transparent union](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007btransparent_005funion_007d-attribute-3101) GCC extension, which essentially allows all pointer types in the union to be treated interchangeably with the union type when used as a function argument.

the macro below the block you quoted from dispatch/object.h explains the connection with `dispatch_queue_t`:

```
#define DISPATCH_DECL(name) typedef struct name##_s *name##_t
```

and then later on in dispatch/queue.h

```
DISPATCH_DECL(dispatch_queue);
```

i.e. `dispatch_queue_t` matches the `_dq` member of the transparent union and hence is a valid type to pass to the `dispatch_object_t` argument of `dispatch_set_target_queue`.

FWIW in Objective-C and C++ the `dispatch_object_t` superclass relationship is expressed using the respective object type system, c.f. the other sections in the `dispatch_object_t` area of dispatch/object.h.

Comment: I take your words "think of dispatch_object_t as the "base class" of all the dispatch object types." Any Docs or book which may address this in more details and worth reading? please recommend, thanks!

Comment: On this topic, I would primarily recommend the `dispatch/object.h` and `os/object.h` headerdoc and the `dispatch_object(3)` manpage. 
If you don't find that sufficiently clear or would like to see this covered in the developer.apple.com documentation, that is worth filing a [bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) about.